# Contact form doesn't show confirmation message in HTML

Tags: php, json, contact-form

I downloaded a great website template and it is all working fine, except for the contact form. there is no more support for the template, so now I'm here.

The form does send an email to me with all the data, but the messages aren't working properly.

1. When the data is filled in wrong, you get a message that it is wrongly filled in. But the message is not deleted when the form is filled in right.
2. When the email is send, there is no message shown that it is sended.
3. When the email is send, the form doesn't reset.

I can't find the sollution...

HTML on the page.

```
        <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="#">
            <p class="contact-name">
                <input id="contact_name" type="text" placeholder="Volledige naam" value="" name="name" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-email">
                <input id="contact_email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail adres" value="" name="email" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-list">
            <select id="contact_list" size="1" name="reason">
                    <option value="1" selected="selected">Kies de reden voor contact</option>
                    <option value="Informatie aanvraag">Informatie aanvraag</option>
                    <option value="Offerte aanvraag">Offerte aanvraag</option>
                    <option value="Anders">Andere reden</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p class="contact-message">
                <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Uw bericht" name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p class="contact-submit">
                <a id="contact-submit" class="submit" href="#">Verstuur uw e-mail</a>
            </p>

            <div id="response">

            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

PHP file (contact.php)

```
<?php
/*
* Contact Form Class
*/


header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$admin_email = 'info@fake.nl'; // Your Email
$message_min_length = 5; // Min Message Length


class Contact_Form{
    function __construct($details, $email_admin, $message_min_length){

        $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
        $this->email = trim($details['email']);
        $this->reason = trim($details['reason']);
        $this->subject = 'Contact via de website'; // Subject 
        $this->message = stripslashes($details['message']);

        $this->email_admin = $email_admin;
        $this->message_min_length = $message_min_length;

        $this->response_status = 1;
        $this->response_html = '';
    }


    private function validateEmail(){
        $regex = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';

        if($this->email == '') { 
            return false;
        } else {
            $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $this->email);
        }

        return empty($string) ? true : false;
    }


    private function validateFields(){
        // Check name
        if(!$this->name)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Voer een naam in</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check email
        if(!$this->email)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Voer een e-mail adres in</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check valid email
        if($this->email && !$this->validateEmail())
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Voer een geldig e-mail adres in</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check valid choice
        if($this->reason == '1')
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Maak een geldige keuze</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check message length
        if(!$this->message || strlen($this->message) < $this->message_min_length)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Voer een bericht in. Het zou minstens '.$this->message_min_length.' tekens moeten hebben.</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }
    }


    private function sendEmail(){
        $mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->reason, $this->message,
             "From: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"
            ."Reply-To: ".$this->email."\r\n"
        ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

        if($mail)
        {
            $this->response_status = 1;
            $this->response_html = '<p>Bedankt voor uw bericht.</p>';
        }
    }


    function sendRequest(){
        $this->validateFields();
        if($this->response_status)
        {
            $this->sendEmail();
        }

        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = $this->response_status;   
        $response['html'] = $this->response_html;

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}


$contact_form = new Contact_Form($_POST, $admin_email, $message_min_length);
$contact_form->sendRequest();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
        <select id="contact_list" size="1" name="reason">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">Kies de reden voor contact</option>
                <option value="2">Informatie aanvraag</option>
                <option value="3">Offerte aanvraag</option>
                <option value="4">Andere reden</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Darn... How simple it can be. It works. Tanks JG Estiot!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the messages problem.

I removed the Reason choice field in the form and the reason class in the PHP.
Not sure why it doesn't work with the reason class in place though.

Maybe somebody can anwser that?